# Invalid Viewstate error

Tags: asp.net

i got this error. how can i solve this?

EVENT # 31890

EVENT LOG Application

EVENT TYPE Warning

OPCODE Info

SOURCE ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0

CATEGORY Web Event

EVENT ID 1309

COMPUTERNAME  WEB2

DATE / TIME  23.07.2010 14:10:09

MESSAGE

Event code: 3005

Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.

Event time: 23.07.2010 14:10:09

Event time (UTC): 23.07.2010 11:10:09

Event ID: 4ccc84959e7849868332f2f75fadcda9

Event sequence: 8713

Event occurrence: 15

Event detail code: 0

Application information:

Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/21/ROOT-3-129243421900200000

Trust level: Full

Application Virtual Path: /

Application Path: E:\Core\eCom\emagaza.deneme.com.tr\

Machine name: WEB2

Process information:

Process ID: 10148

Process name: w3wp.exe

Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Exception information:

Exception type: HttpException

Exception message:

Invalid viewstate.
at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptStringWithIV(String s, IVType ivType) at System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Request information:

Request URL: http://emagaza.deneme.com.tr/WebResource.axd?d=_uDhmp2fdIuSell_URL= 
Request path: /WebResource.axd

User:

Is authenticated: False 
Authentication Type: 
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Thread information: 
Thread ID: 29 
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Is impersonating: False

Stack trace: at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptStringWithIV(String s, IVType ivType)
at System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Custom event details:

Answer (score 1):

This error is because if you see the request link that ask the WebResource.asd is miss the corect code key. Is something that happend not by your actuall pages but other scan programs of your web pages that try to test and see what they can do to your site...

**So there is nothing to solve here. Just ignore it.**